# How to read files from an archive file in android

Tags: android, file

I have an archive file with the extension ".dth". In it I have two files *colors.txt* and *stack.txt*. I put it in the sdk directory of my phone memory. Now trying to read the archive and LogCat print the contents of each file. I used the code:

```
private void readThemeFile()
{
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myFile.dth");
    FileInputStream is;

    try
    {
        is = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        ZipEntry ze;

        if (zis.getNextEntry() == null) Log.d("Next Entry", "is null");

        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int count;

            while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                baos.write(buffer, 0, count);

            String filename = ze.getName();

            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

            Log.d("File Name:", filename);
            Log.d("Bytes Length:", bytes.length + "");

            zis.close();
        }
    } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) { Log.d("Message:", "File not found."); }

    catch (IOException e) { Log.d("Message:", "IOException occurred."); }
}
```

However After reading stack.txt it got an IO Exception:

```
01-08 19:58:20.238: D/File Name:(1202): stack.txt
01-08 19:58:20.238: D/Bytes Length:(1202): 46
01-08 19:58:20.248: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
01-08 19:58:20.248: I/keystore(1271): uid: 1000 action: e -> 7 state: 3 -> 3 retry: 4
01-08 19:58:20.248: D/Message:(1202): IOException occurred.
```

Furthermore, if I put folders in my archive the code zis.getNextEntry() returns null. Why does it happen? Why can't I read both of files in the archive?

Comment: Why change the extension?

Comment: It's a way the file not to be identified at first glance.

Comment: I think my question is crystal clear. Why has someone down voted it?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." See also the question checklist: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @laalto You know or not, every question is not deeply specific. General questions form the basis of specific ones.

Comment: Good, code! Now, consider adding `, e` at the end of the exception logging to get a helpful stacktrace for your IOException.

Comment: Great, it worked. I placed the zis.close() after the while loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just asking for guidance, and not have a specific questions. I'll simply answer by saying look into `zipinputstream`

Comment: Thanks, does this class treat archive files with different extensions like a zip folder?

Answer (score -1):

```
 prefix -> filename
 suffix -> extension
 File file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix)

 directory -> directory(File)[It may be necessary to set this property to an existing, writable directory for this method to work properly]
 File file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, directory)
```

Comment: Thanks @sush, it may be really helpful in my other cases. I'll give it a try soon.